# NSCollectionView не изменяет размер

Tags: cocoa, objective-c, macos

Не могу понять:Есть NSWindow, на котором расположен NSCollectionView (который ресайзится вместе с окном). Использую метод windowDidResize, для проверки ресайза окна. Когда окно максимизировать (зеленая кнопка), Размеры NSWindow и NSCollectionView изменяются. Если вернуть окно в прежнее состояние той же кнопкой, то NSWindow и NSCollectionView (фактически) изменяет размеры, но NSCollectionView в логе выдает размер предыдущий, как буд-то он остался максимизирован.

```
2014-05-14 10:39:24.804 NSCollectionViewTest[4552:303] _window 701.000000
2014-05-14 10:39:24.805 NSCollectionViewTest[4552:303] collectionView 1344.000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проанализировав структуру компонента NSCollectionView (NSView -> NSScrollView -> NSClipView) взялся за обработку NSScrollView. Как оказалось, NSScrollView меняет свой размер (ширину и высоту) если окно максимизировать, а потом восстановить обратно. Почему этого не делает NSCollectionView, я так и не понял. В общем достиг желаемого результата используя размеры NSScrollView.

Суть заключалась в том чтобы выравнивать итемы в NSCollectionView согласно размеру (ширины) компонента, т.е. как бы центрировать итемы. Т.к. обычно при ресайзе окна, справа образовывалось пустое пространство. Такая же ситуация была с максимизацией и восстановлением окна.